# Why permutations are counted in Simple random sampling with replacement?

Tags: probability, sampling

Why are ordered pairs counted in Simple random sampling with replacement but not in without replacement? Is there any intuition behind it as to why when we take samples(simple random sampling) with replacement we want distinct permutations of members rather than distinct combinations?

Edit:
To clarify; (x1,x2) and (x2,x1) are treated different in SRSWR but not in SRSWOR. Why permutations are counted in SRSWR and in SRSWOR combinations are counted?

Comment: What makes you think order matters for srswr?

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: Even with your edit I don’t see an issue. Please explain a situation in which x1,x2 is treated differently than x2,x1

Comment: take population set to be A = {1,2,3} now select a sample of size 2 with replacement these are {1,1}{1,2}{1,3}{2,1}{2,2}{2,3}{3,1}{3,2}{3,3} and without replacement {1,2}{1,3}{2,3}. Now with replacement why {2,1} and {1,2} both are counted, and not just one of them.

Comment: Okay? What’s the problem? Why exactly are you sampling? What are you trying to do?

Comment: My problem is why we are doing this, can't we just ignore {2,1} and {1,2} and just count one of them, say {1,2}, just like in case of SRSWOR  so we get  {1,1}{1,2}{1,3}{2,2}{2,3}{3,3} means 6 samples and not 9(3^2) samples. And it makes sense to count only one of {1,2} {2,1}, so i'm just asking is there any particular reason to do this?

Comment: Well you can. If you want to sample two people with replacement 2,1 and 1,2 are indifferent to you. If you want to sample an ordered pair then they are different but it’s up to you what you are trying to achieve